Ошибка : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Как сделать так чтобы когда в базе данных ничего не находилось не выдавало ошибку
    username = (c.fetchone()[0])
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Код
def cliked():
    global username
    global usernamenew
    # получаем имя пользователя
    usernamenew = username_entry.get()
    search_term = usernamenew
    c.execute(
        "SELECT username FROM account WHERE username LIKE ?",
        ('%' + search_term + '%',))

    username = str(c.fetchone()[0])


Используйте обработчик исключений try, так Вы сможете обработать Вашу ошибку без прекращения работы приложения

Спасибо, помогло!

Можно просто проверить, что оно вернуло, и брать первый элемент, только если там не None:
def cliked():
    ...
    fetchone = c.fetchone()
    if fetchone is not None:
        username = str(fetchone[0])

